# Azure Signal R Service not working on Blazor Wasm app

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, azure-signalr

I am trying to set up `Azure Signal R Service`. Currently, I can get it working if I send a message to ALL clients but if I try and use Groups it doesn't send any messages. I suspect it has to do with the `Azure signal R Service`. I am running this locally atm

in My Web Api Startup.cs I have the following:

```
   services.AddSignalR()
                .AddAzureSignalR(options => options.Endpoints = new[]
                    {
                        new ServiceEndpoint(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSignalRConnection"))
                    });
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/SingalRHub`enter code here`");            
        });
```

Then In my Hub:

```
 public class SignalRHub: Hub
  {
        public async Task Join(long deviceId)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, deviceId);     
        }

       public async Task ReadTime(int deviceId)
       {
            await Clients.Group(deviceId).SendAsync($"ReadResponse", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
}
```

On my client side: (Blazor wasm app)

```
private async Task InitiaizeSignalR()
{

    //Intialize signal R
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/SignalRHub"))            
        .Build();

    _hubConnection.On<string>("ReadResponse", (message) =>
    {           
        Console.WriteLine($"Read Response: {message}");          
    });

    //Connect to hub
    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();

    //Register to get messages for this DeviceId
    await _hubConnection.SendAsync("Join", DeviceId);
}
```

Now the stange thing is that when I call this on my client, I dono get any response. However If i change it to:

`await Clients.All.SendAsync($"ReadResponse", DateTime.Now.ToString());`

Then my clinet will get the message?

Comment: AddToGroupAsync expects a string not a long.
`AddToGroupAsync(string connectionId, string groupName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))`